# Approach to Load data from Master to Child objects from Legacy database

Tags: data-loader, migration-tool

We have an oracle database with 100,000 records which has a master table called Application and it has a child called Application Individual and each Application individual has one level children like Income, Expense, Assets. So we have a 3 level master detail from Application to Application Individual and Individual  Asset, expense etc. We have atleast 75 objects to be loaded worth 100,000 records. I was thinking of using a tool to load this data like Jitterbit or Talend. What is the best approach to do this data load? In salesforce, we have the same object structure and fields and we have some mapping? What would be the recommended approach to load the data one time?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: Talend is an excellent tool.For 1 level relationship i have used this and mapping is too simple .Haven't tried using for n level relationship .If its just 1,00,000 in total even jitter bit is good option.First all the master record can be loaded and child records can be loaded next using external id to establish relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have an external ID field on each object that can be a parent to another object. This field will be used to contain the Oracle ID of each record. Then I would load data from the top levels down. First, start with Application. When you upload Application Individual, use the [Upsert](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) call to insert the data and then use the external ID fields as the foreign key. Jitterbit can support mapping to external Ids for the parent records.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Mohit for your reply. Have you guys used Jitterbit to do this in your organization and is there any limitation i should be aware of on this tool?

Comment: I've used the full version of Jitterbit for this. The benefit there is that you can chain operations so if you needed to sync data multiplpe times, you could have On Succcess actions to call the next set of data. I believe the free version of Jitterbit should have no problem syncing the data one table at a time, you just couldn't set it up to automatically do all of them.

Comment: This was going to be my answer as well. External Id's are critical for this type of data migration